# Formatting String Variables that contain numbers/dates for printing in C#

Tags: c#, string, methods, formatting, .net

Maybe it's a n00b question but I've looked at the .net/C# MSDN Library and on this site and have yet to come to a clear answer... say I had For Ex: 
(this is not *exactly* the problem, as I'm not creating the string but reading them out of a DB. But serves to illustrate what I'm working with...)

```
string dob = "01/02/1990";
dob.ToString("MM/dd/YY"); //however, I can't do this. compiler gives me an error...
```

likely because it is already a string? How then could I get the string into the format that I want using specifiers, when it's already a string?
I know I could convert it to something else (a DateTime for Ex) and convert back to string using the ToString()...but this seems counter productive... to me at least

I also have several other "kinds" of string variables I'm trying to display into specific formats whilst saving them to a Idictionary for printing into a pdf's fields.
For ex:

```
d["amount"] = prod.sales.StringAmount; //(here StringSmount holds say 50000 (gotten from a DB), which I want to display as "50,000")
```

However, I also can't do prod.sales.StringAmount.ToString("N", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture); cuz it's already a string! Is there an easy way to do this

or need I mess with String Buffers or the StringBuilder class??
thanks!

Comment: FYI You can call `ToString()` on a string no problem - but why would you?

Comment: why not make `dob` a `DateTime` object, and covert that using `ToString()` ... also your `dob.ToString("MM/dd/YY")` is missing a semi-colon

Comment: The reason I call ToString() on a string: I already have string fields loaded into biz objects from a DB... and I *have* to format them so they print nicely onto a pdf. Thus, I couldn't figure out if there was an easy way to do this. Ie: say I have:

Comment: `var strdate = "07/20/1997";
 var newstrdatefomat = strdate.ToString("MM/dd/yy");` but I was getting an error. I now see I'll have to use the String.Format() or convert-and-reconvert back to string... thanks for the tips guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
DateTime dob = DateTime.Parse("01/02/1990");
```

and then

```
dob.ToString("MM/dd/YY");
```

will work.

Note that `DateTime.Parse()` has various options for the possible date-time formats to accept, and that there is also a `TryParse()` version that returns `false` if the string is not a valid date - instead than throwing an exception. There are also `DateTime.ParseExact()` and `DateTime.TryParseExact()` variations.

Use the same approach for other data types beside date-times: first convert the input string in the correct data type (integer, float etc) - using the various `Parse()` or `TryParse()` methods, and then format the result of this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

ToString returns a value without modifying the original.

Instead of

```
dob.ToString("MM/dd/YY");
```

use

```
dob = dob.ToString("MM/dd/YY");
```

Comment: this seemed to give me a error when I tried it... something about the IFormatProvider being wrong... `"Arguemnt type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.IFormatProvider'`

Answer (score 1):

First parse the string into a `DateTime` instance (via the `Parse()` or `TryParse()` methods). On the `DateTime` Instance you can then call `ToString`(..).

Answer (score 1):

Using the format provided above, you would need to convert back to DateTime to use the .ToString("MM/dd/YY") format.  The reason why is ToString is used to convert an object/value to a string representation and the DateTime object is nice enough to accept a format.

If you want to Format what is already a string, then you should be using String.Format.  Visit this link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx.  This link shows the standard numeric formatters.

You may also want to create your own string format. Look into IFormatProvider and ICustomFormatter:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend first parsing it into a number/DateTime and then using the string formatting variables.  For an example of why this can be necessary, consider that your "01/02/1990" string is ambiguous between Jan 2 and Feb 1, unless you parse it using `DateTime.ParseExact`.

I'd recommend this over 'rolling your own' (e.g. with StringBuilder) so that you can use the built-in culture-sensitive string formatting abilities of .NET.